# Redis Timeseries Pipeline with Python

Tags: python, redis, pipeline

I am looking to use pipeline to insert data into a redis Timeseries but cannot find a way to ts.add via pipeline.

I can do basic example with get / set:

import redis

import json

redis_client = redis.Redis(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', port='xxxxx', password='xxxx')

pipe = redis_client.pipeline()

pipe.set(1,'apple')

pipe.set(2,'orange')

pipe.execute()

I cant find a way to insert into a timeseries:

import redis

import json

redis_client = redis.Redis(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', port='xxxxx', password='xxxx')

pipe = redis_client.pipeline()

pipe.ts.add(TS1,1652683016,55)    #<----- this is what I want to do!

pipe.ts.add(TS1,1652683017,59)    #<----- this is what I want to do!

pipe.execute()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this writing (redis-py 4.3.1) there exists another pipeline object on the timeseries class itself.  The following will work:

```
import redis

r = redis.Redis()
pipe = r.ts().pipeline()
pipe.add("TS1", 1, 123123123123)
pipe.add("TS1", 2, 123123123451)
...
pipe.add("TS1", 15, 123123126957)
pipe.execute()
```